# Windows Phone: How to determine if application is connected to the internet when it starts

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

Is there a way to find out if my windows phone application is connected to the internet as soon as it loads.

To be clear, I'm not interested in listening to Network Changes. I just want to know what the connection status is at one point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile(), which will return null if the device is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score -1):

There is the [`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which will return true if a network connection is available. With the caveat that:

> A network connection is considered to be available if any network interface is marked "up" and is not a loopback or tunnel interface.

There is no guarantee that your remote host will still be reachable, even if you are connected to The Internet